# Passing a block variable to grep?

Tags: ruby, grep

When I do:

```
["bar","quax"].grep(/bar/)
```

The output is:

```
=> ["bar"]
```

If I do:

```
["bar","quax"].grep(/fish/)
```

The output is:

```
=> []
```

I decided to take it further by attempting to pass a block to `grep`, but it did not work.

```
["foo", "bar", "baz", "quax"].each do |some_word|
   ["fish","jones"].grep(/some_word/)
end
```

The output is:

```
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quax"]
```

I am curious why my extension doesn't work, as it seems fairly straightforward. Or, is it simply illegal to do?

Comment: So uhh.. where are you passing a block to grep?

Comment: block variable I meant `some_word`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each` is iterating over your array but you aren't modifying it. So it's just looping a few times, calling grep which is effectively doing nothing (technically it's returning *something*, you're just not doing anything with it), then returning the original array.

You need to be doing something with the return value of grep - but it's not clear to me what that is supposed to be (I don't understand why you are using `each` at all?)

Also, some_word in this case is taken literally as "some_word". You should interpolate your regex like `.grep(/#{some_word}/)`

Answer (score 0):

```
["foo", "bar", "baz", "quax"].each do |some_word|
   ["fish","jones"].grep(/some_word/)
end
```

isn't correct. `some_word` is the parameter to the block, but `/some_word/` is a regular expression that matches the string `'some_word'`, whether that is the entire string or just a sub-string:

```
%w[some_word not_some_word_anymore].grep(/some_word/)
# => ["some_word", "not_some_word_anymore"]
```

If you want to use the variable/parameter `some_word` inside the regular expression, you have to substitute it in somehow. A simple way to do it is:

```
/#{ some_word }/
```

or:

```
Regexp.new( some_word )
```

For instance:

```
foo = 'some_word'
/#{ foo }/      # => /some_word/
Regexp.new(foo) # => /some_word/
```

The reason:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz", "quax"].each do |some_word|
end
```

returns the same array, is that is how `each` behaves. We don't care usually. If you want to transform that array, then use `map`:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz", "quax"].map { |some_word| some_word.size }
# => [3, 3, 3, 4]
```

If you're trying to reduce the array use something like `grep` or `select` or `reject`:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz", "quax"].reject { |some_word| some_word['oo'] }
# => ["bar", "baz", "quax"]

["foo", "bar", "baz", "quax"].select { |some_word| some_word['oo'] }
# => ["foo"]
```